# Cocos2d SpriteSheet Animation

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

everywhere i look i find code on how to run an animation using file created from zwoptex, but it is using deprecated code. I can't find code on how to run the animation using CCSpriteBatchNode.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which version of cocos2d are you using?

Comment: 0.99.5 is the version i am using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I do animations using files created from zwoptex, but I am using CCSpriteFrameCache. I don't get any warnings, so I suppose this code is not deprecated:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"frameSheet.plist"];
NSMutableArray* frames = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfFrames; ++i) {
    [frames addObject:
     [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"frame-%03d.png", i]]];
}
CCAnimation* anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay:0.3f];
```

Texture file is named `frameSheet.png`, plist file is `frameSheet.plist`, and the composing images are named `frame-001.png` ... `frame-100.png`.

Let me know if this helps you.

EDIT:

strangely, for me `animationWithFrames:frames` is not deprecated:

[image],

it says "from 0.99.5" and I have no issues with my animations...

Comment: CCAnimation* anim = [CCAnimation frames delay:0.3f];
this line i don't get. i get an error Expected ] before delay and a warning CCAnimation may not respond to +frames

Comment: Sorry, double clicking in Safari is not the same as double clicking in Xcode and I replaced more text than I wanted; the correct line is: `CCAnimation* anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay:0.3f];
;

Comment: Yeah a lot of class names were changed in the newer versions.  This should work though.

Comment: [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay:0.3f] is deprecated
when i use this code, only a small part of the image is shown. I think a quarter.